# Heroku new Buildpack with Laravel

Tags: heroku, deployment, laravel, buildpack

Today I received a email from Heroku announcing their new buildpack for PHP.
Since then when I make a new deployment of my Laravel 4 app I get this error:

### Application Error An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

I even make a new app with clean code and I got the same error.
The git deployment show no errors.

This is my log from Papertrail:

> pr 29 21:04:07 shielded-ocean-5349 heroku/web.1:  State changed from
>   crashed to starting  Apr 29 21:04:08 shielded-ocean-5349 heroku/web.1:
>   Starting process with command `sh www/conf/web-boot.sh`  Apr 29
>   21:04:08 shielded-ocean-5349 heroku/web.1:  Process exited with status
>   2  Apr 29 21:04:13 shielded-ocean-5349 app/web.1:  sed: can't read
>   /app/apache/conf/httpd.conf: No such file or directory  Apr 29
>   21:04:13 shielded-ocean-5349 app/web.1:  touch: cannot touch
>   `/app/apache/logs/access_log': No such file or directory  Apr 29
>   21:04:13 shielded-ocean-5349 app/web.1:  exec: 25:
>   /app/apache/bin/httpd: not found  Apr 29 21:04:13 shielded-ocean-5349
>   app/web.1:  www/conf/web-boot.sh: 16: cannot create
>   /app/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Directory nonexistent  Apr 29 21:04:13
>   shielded-ocean-5349 app/web.1:  www/conf/web-boot.sh: 16: cannot
>   create /app/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Directory nonexistent  Apr 29
>   21:04:13 shielded-ocean-5349 app/web.1:  www/conf/web-boot.sh: 16:
>   cannot create /app/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Directory nonexistent  Apr
>   29 21:04:13 shielded-ocean-5349 app/web.1:  www/conf/web-boot.sh: 17:
>   cannot create /app/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Directory nonexistent  Apr
>   29 21:04:13 shielded-ocean-5349 app/web.1:  touch: cannot touch`
>   /app/apache/logs/error_log': No such file or directory

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer. 
I was using this custom buildpack: https://github.com/thomaswelton/laravel

I change this line (in Procfile file):

```
web:    sh www/conf/web-boot.sh
```

To this one:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public
```

where "public" is my root folder.
Also, I didn't need "conf" folder anymore.

Hope it helps